# Question Authors Should Be Able to Prevent or Remove Closed-As-Duplicates

Tags: support

I placed a question. Few members thought this is duplicate and marked that duplicate. After discussion and their solution, I realized, that this is not duplicate. Now, there is no option that I can remove duplicate tag. I can place another question. What the heck?

Who is maintaining these policies? Please review. It's annoying. If I place my question again, other members will do hurry and will mark my question as duplicate another time. (Either there should be a prevention flag from author to do not mark to duplicate or author should have rights to remove duplicate link.)

Please suggest. I am newbie. It doesn't mean that I cannot have unique or different or out of the box questions.

Here is link of my question:
[Transfer execution control from one class to another in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761344/transfer-execution-control-from-one-class-to-another-in-java)

Comment: This isn't perhaps not the most constructive way to either convey your feedback or ask a question.

Comment: Edit the question to decrease its duplicate-ness; it will automatically go into a queue to be reviewed and possibly reopened.

Comment: Strange. I am just irritated due to this duplicate policy. Its looks me like nobody listen to me (i.e. I have no rights for my own question). what way you suggest dear. Devnull ?

Comment: Editing your question will place it in the reopen review queue where community members can decide whether it really is a dupe or not. Asking a user with 3000 reputation to vote for reopen will do the same, but please only ask in the comments of your question or chat - not on other posts.

Comment: I didn't see if you already consumed everything that is written in [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the links it provides for even more guidance. That can help you in your effort to improve your question.

Answer (score 11):

> Who is maintaining these policies?

The entire community is. Everybody with at least 3000 reputation can vote to close *and reopen* questions, and there are publicly visible queues for these users for review. You will also be able to do this when you have 3000 points.

If you have edited a question and you believe it should be reopened, I'd first try just leaving a comment on the question to that effect. People will see it. If, after some time passes, you feel it is still not getting attention, you can always come here or ask in chat, but you will have better luck if you stay polite and remain open to the possibility that maybe your question will stay closed.

Once you have enough reputation, you can simply vote to reopen it, then it will appear in the review queue and will usually be reopened quickly (if it actually should be reopened).

---

For the specific question you are asking about (and this often works in general for this type of thing), I suggest editing it by taking a look at the answers in the "duplicate" link, and then editing your question to explain why those solutions are not appropriate/working for you. I think, in this particular case, taking this approach will get your question moving in the right direction.

Comment: This seems useless forum for me. Please feel to delete my account.

Comment: @Asvhini Community members cannot delete people's accounts, but if you would like to delete your account, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account

Comment: @Asvhini also, Stack Overflow ***is not a forum***. It's a [Question & Answer site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). It shares some similarities to forums, but it's not entirely the same.

Answer (score 7):

Let's start with the title:

> Question Authors Should Be Able to Prevent or Remove Closed-As-Duplicates

Question authors are *already* able to prevent their questions from being closed as duplicates and are *already* able to reopen such questions.

The way to prevent a question from being closed as a duplicate is to **anticipate possible responses.** The author has to look at the question through the eyes of readers. If someone saw this question would they suggest a solution that might seem reasonable but would not work *in this specific case*? If the author is able to anticipate such responses, then they should formulate their question to **clearly explain** why their problem would not benefit from such solution.

The way to reopen such a question is to examine the question to which the "this is a duplicate of" link points and its answers. Then the author should edit the question to **clearly explain** why their problem would not benefit from such solution.

The explanation (or a summary of it that invites people to look at the question again) could be in a comment but I don't recommend putting it *only* in a comment because people don't always read comments or go down a long list of old comments. **The explanation belongs to the body of the question.**

In my explanation above I've bolded "**clearly explain**" because in a great many cases this is precisely where authors who want their question reopened fail. Instead of clearly explaining, they *assert* that their question is not a duplicate.

- "My question is not a duplicate. Reopen it!"
- "My question is not a duplicate because the solution to that other question does not apply. Reopen it!"
- "My question is not a duplicate because I don't want to use an array!"

The first two examples above are terrible and won't prompt me to support reopening the question. The 3rd example *might* work in *some* very simple cases but in very many cases the question that would come up in the mind of readers is "why is an array not working for you?" The explanation must have some substance.

**Another way authors fail to get their posts reopened is when their posts suffer from multiple problems.** So maybe they make a convincing point regarding the fact that their post is not a duplicate but their post still suffers from being unclear or has some other flaw. Or they demonstrate that their post is not a duplicate of question A but then it sounds like a duplicate of question B.

When I review reopen requests I will not vote to reopen a question that has addressed *one* problem but still contains *other* problems, even if the original close reason is moot. There is no point in going through the exercise of reopening the question only to have other users then vote again to close it because the question is worthy of being closed for another reason than the original one.

You are suggesting a change to the way SE sites operate:

> (Either there should be a prevention flag from author to do not mark to duplicate or author should have rights to remove duplicate link.)

No, there should not. **Whatever powers question authors already have is all the power they should have.** And the reason for this is because the contents on Stack Exchange sites really belong to the community. In a comment you said this:

> (i.e. I have no rights for my own question)

I'm not sure that "right" is the right word here. You have some powers regarding your own questions but these powers are limited because, and this is very important, **the posts you submit to Stack Exchange sites belong to the community on those sites.**

---

Regarding the specific question that prompted you to post here, this is the reason you have given as to why it is not a duplicate:

> Note* -JUnitCore() is not the option. It doesn't for my scenario. -I do not want to run Junit inside my main program. I want it to run as separate application.

The question that immediately arises for me is "why?" Why do you want to run it as a separate application. And more importantly, why can't you just then run your application and the junit stuff like you'd run *any* two separate applications? Indeed I see that Jason C in a comment has suggested a solution that amounts to the way one would run any two run-of-the-mill separate applications. And you replied "Seems good option to me or May be excellent idea.", which makes your question a duplicate of the myriad questions that have to do with running multiple applications from a script.